# Есть ли стандартный алгоритм перемещения?

Tags: c++

Есть алгоритм copy, он просто копирует. А есть ли алгоритм перемещения?

Answer (score 2):

Там же где и `std::copy` есть и [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)

Comment: move это просто static_cast

Comment: @Semerkin, не только. Есть и другой [`move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move).